# Can I get relative path of current site with single function?

Tags: 2013, jquery, spservices

I am trying to build a breadcrumb using JS and SPServices. When I browse for a page like

```
http://sharepoint.com/sites/News/pages/f1/f2/default.aspx
```

the breadcrumb should show

> SharePoint.com > f1 > f2 > Page Title

Each node should have hyperlink to their URL accordingly.

By using `$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite()`, that is `http://sharepoint.com/sites/News/` in above example.

However I have no idea how to get the suffix, or relative path, of the site or subsite (i.e. `pages/f1/f2/default.aspx`)

By using `window.location.pathname`, I will get `/sites/News/pages/f1/f2/default.aspx` which is not my need. I need to get `/pages/f1/f2/default.aspx` only.

Also, I have some subsites with URL like:

```
http://sharepoint.com/sites/News/subsite/

http://sharepoint.com/sites/News/subsite/subsub/

http://sharepoint.com/sites/News/subsite/subsubsub/
```

Hence I need a function always return the "relative path" of the current site. Does this function exist?

Comment: Are you using SP2013?

Comment: Yes. SP2013 on-premise standard edition

Answer (score 4):

Mark,  See if [this](http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/) can help you.

If you are writing the custom code [this](http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/02/08/a-single-breadcrumb-for-all-sharepoint-pages/) can set you the starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But the OOB breadcrumb do not work on publishing infrastructure pages. I need to build my own.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using an on-prem version, so I suggest using out-of-the-box ways of achieving this.

In the masterpage there should already exist tools to help you achieve this.

In SharePoint 2010 (I haven't fooled around with Masterpages in 2013 a lot) the way to solve what you are asking for was to do this:

```
<div name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" ID="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
            <SharePoint:ProjectProperty ID="ProjectProperty1" Property="Title" runat="server" />
        </SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
<span id="onetidPageTitleSeparator" class="s4-nothome s4-bcsep s4-titlesep">
    <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow ID="ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow1" runat="server" />
</span>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />
```

I'm sure there exist 2013 equivalents of this. You might have to throw in a bit of your own HTML markup to make it look the way you want.